# How to create chaining API after read_to_string was changed to take a buffer?

Tags: rust, chaining

I'm trying to port my library [clog](https://github.com/thoughtram/clog) to the latest Rust version.

Rust changed a lot in the previous month and so I'm scratching my head over this code asking myself if there's really no way anymore to write this in a completely chained way?

```
fn get_last_commit () -> String {

    let output = Command::new("git")
                    .arg("rev-parse")
                    .arg("HEAD")
                    .output()
                    .ok().expect("error invoking git rev-parse");

    let encoded = String::from_utf8(output.stdout).ok().expect("error parsing output of git rev-parse");

    encoded
}
```

In an older version of Rust the code could be written like that

```
pub fn get_last_commit () -> String {

    Command::new("git")
            .arg("rev-parse")
            .arg("HEAD")
            .spawn()
            .ok().expect("failed to invoke rev-parse")
            .stdout.as_mut().unwrap().read_to_string()
            .ok().expect("failed to get last commit")
}
```

It seems there is no `read_to_string()` method anymore that doesn't take a buffer which makes it hard to implement a chaining API unless I'm missing something.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I figured I can use `map` to get it chaining.

```
fn get_last_commit () -> String {

    Command::new("git")
            .arg("rev-parse")
            .arg("HEAD")
            .output()
            .map(|output| {
                String::from_utf8(output.stdout).ok().expect("error reading into string")
            })
            .ok().expect("error invoking git rev-parse")
}
```

Actually I wonder if I could use `and then` but it seems the errors don't line up correctly ;)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this was changed to allow reusing buffers/avoiding allocations.

Another alternative is to use `read_to_string` and manually provide the buffer:

```
pub fn get_last_commit () -> String {
    let mut string = String::new();

    Command::new("git")
            .arg("rev-parse")
            .arg("HEAD")
            .spawn()
            .ok().expect("failed to invoke rev-parse")
            .stdout.as_mut().unwrap()
            .read_to_string(&mut string)
            .ok().expect("failed to get last commit");

    string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This API was changed so that you didn't have to re-allocate a new `String` each time. However, as you've noticed, there's some convenience loss if you don't care about allocation. It might be a good idea to suggest re-adding this back in, like what happened with `Vec::from_elem`. Maybe open a small RFC?

Comment: OK, I promise to write one. Not sure if still today because it's midnight already but I promise I will. I'm still scratching my head over this one ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022016/how-to-get-resultt-e1-aligned-with-resultt-e2-in-rust

Comment: I actually even started writing it ;)

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/cburgdorf/rfcs/blob/read_to_string/text/0841-read_to_string_without_buffer.md

Answer (score 1):

While it may make sense to try to add this back to the standard library, here's a version of `read_to_string` that allocates on its own that you can use today:

```
#![feature(io)]

use std::io::{self,Read,Cursor};

trait MyRead: Read {
    fn read_full_string(&mut self) -> io::Result<String> {
        let mut s = String::new();
        let r = self.read_to_string(&mut s);
        r.map(|_| s)
    }
}

impl<T> MyRead for T where T: Read {}

fn main() {
    let bytes = b"hello";
    let mut input = Cursor::new(bytes);
    let s = input.read_full_string();
    println!("{}", s.unwrap());
}
```

This should allow you to use the chaining style you had before.