# How to get Result<T, E1> aligned with Result<T,E2>?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have this code

```
fn get_last_commit () -> String {

    Command::new("git")
            .arg("rev-parse")
            .arg("HEAD")
            .output()
            .map(|output| {
                String::from_utf8(output.stdout).ok().expect("error reading into string")
            })
            .ok().expect("error invoking git rev-parse")
}
```

I'd like to be able to cut the `ok().expect(..)` a bit down so that I ideally have something like that:

```
fn get_last_commit () -> String {

    Command::new("git")
            .arg("rev-parse")
            .arg("HEAD")
            .output()
            .and_then(|output| {
                String::from_utf8(output.stdout)
            })
            .ok().expect("error invoking git rev-parse")
}
```

However, that doesn't work because the errors don't line up leaving me with:

```
    mismatched types:
     expected `core::result::Result<_, std::io::error::Error>`,
        found `core::result::Result<collections::string::String, collections::string::FromUtf8Error>`
    (expected struct `std::io::error::Error`,
        found struct `collections::string::FromUtf8Error`)
```

I know the error handling changed quite a bit within the last month and I have the feeling there should be away to get them aligned without too much hassle. I seem unable to figure it out though.

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/a/28912145/497043 to be of value.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the closure passed to the `and_then` needs to return a `Result` with the same error type as the `Result` that `and_then` was called on; otherwise, there's no single type that `and_then` could return; `and_then` maps one `Ok` type to another, but keeps the error type the same.

Since you are just throwing away the error value by converting it to an option with `ok()` that you unwrap anyhow, you can do that before calling `and_then`, and within the closure, as the `Option` type returned by `and_then` on an `Option` only depends on the value returned by the closure:

```
fn get_last_commit () -> String {

    Command::new("git")
            .arg("rev-parse")
            .arg("HEAD")
            .output()
            .ok()
            .and_then(|output| {
                String::from_utf8(output.stdout).ok()
            })
            .expect("error invoking git rev-parse")
}
```

If you actually cared about the error value, you would need to define your own error type that could contain either of the two types of errors, and wrap either of the errors up. The `FromError` trait and `try!` macro offer a convenient way to is wrap up the value and return it from one of several places in your function, though in this case `map_err` would probably be a better way to do that as you are doing it all via chained method calls rather than separate statements.

```
enum MyError {
    Io(IoError),
    Utf8(FromUtf8Error)
}

fn get_last_commit () -> Result<String,MyError> {

    Command::new("git")
            .arg("rev-parse")
            .arg("HEAD")
            .output()
            .map_err(MyError::Io)
            .and_then(|output| {
                String::from_utf8(output.stdout)
                       .map_err(MyError::Utf8)
            })
}
```

If you notice, this parallels the earlier solution fairly closely, coercing both of the result types into a single common type; in the first solution, it just throws away the error value by using `ok()`, while in the second, it preserves the error value so you can return it, but you now need the extra machinery of a type that could wrap either.

Comment: Enum variants can be used as functions, so there is no need to create closures explicitly: `.map_err(MyError::Io)` and `.map_err(MyError::Utf8)` should work as well.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Ah, I was wondering if that would work but hadn't checked. Thanks!