# Equivalent of map_err that uses from_error automatically

Tags: rust

`Result` has an `map_err` function that allows you to map `Result<T, E>` to a `Result<T, F>` by applying a function to the error value.

For types that implement `FromError`, the most natural function to apply would just be `FromError::from_error`, leading to something like the following:

```
foo()
  .map_err(FromError::from_error)
  .and_then(|val| {
      val.do_something().map_err(FromError::from_err)
  })
```

It seems that for this kind of use case, there should be a less cumbersome method defined on `Result<T, E> where E: Error` that calls `FromError::from_error` less verbosely, something like the following but with a better name:

```
foo()
  .wrap_err()
  .and_then(|val| {
      val.do_something().wrap_err()
  })
```

This would just be equivalent to `.map_err(FromError::from_error)`, simply shorter and more convenient for when you're doing this kind of method chaining.

Is there something like this defined anywhere? I could not find it, though I'm not sure if I was looking in all of the right places in the documentation.

This question was inspired my my answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29022330/69755), in which I described both `FromError` for use with `try!` but realized it didn't help with the method-chaining style being used there.

Comment: you might be interested in the `?` postfix operator: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23040

Comment: @ker Interesting, I hadn't seen that. That operator seems to just be syntactic sugar for `try!`, which interrupts control flow to return if you see an error value, while the `wrap_err` method that I describe propagates the error through the chained method calls. That may be what is more useful in a wider variety of cases, but there are cases where getting a `Result` from chained method calls without interrupting your control flow may also be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such method at least at present. I believe that in practical situations `try!` is used somewhat more commonly than the method chaining approach (and it tends to yield nicer code in my opinion), so it’s not been such an important consideration.

Potentially more interesting as a design consideration would be changing `and_then` et al. to use `FromError`:

```rust
pub fn and_then<U, E2: FromError<E>, F: FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, E2>>
               (self, op: F) -> Result<U, E2> {
    match self {
        Ok(t) => op(t),
        Err(e) => Err(FromError::from_error(e)),
    }
}
```

… but I don’t believe this will happen, because they’re marked stable and it would be a just slightly backwards-incompatible change.

Comment: That's true, this would become even more convenient if `and_then` did this automatically. I think you would need to call `op(t).map_err(FromError::from_error)` in the `Ok` case as well.

Comment: Actually, would it be backwards incompatible? There's a catch-all `impl<E> FromError<E> for E` so that all types implement `from_error` to themselves as the identity function, so for all existing code that uses `and_then` where both error types are the same, the types would work out and the `FromError` calls would just do nothing (and hopefully be optimized out). Is there a way in which that would not be considered backwards-compatible?

Comment: It would be slightly incompatible because some generic combinations that can be resolved uniquely at present would no longer be able to be resolved uniquely.